# How to connect keyboard input and python app output to QPlainTextEdit and QTextBrowser

Tags: python, qt4, pyqt4

I have been attempting to write my first app in python using a Qt Designer and pyuic4 generated GUi.py file. After beating my head against this particular wall for several weeks, while pursuing the pyQt4 and QT helps files and docs, I am no nearer a solution. I think I may be in way over my now swollen and bruised head. If someone would be so kind as to just give me a leg up on the basics, as far as how to connect the keyboard input and python app output to QplainTextEdit and QTextBrowser, I would be forever in your debt.

I've read for days on the topic of Qt and have read through one or two tutorials, but none give the info. that I've been looking for. But volumes on buttons(clicked), Dials, and writing to and reading from XML files.

I am sure a more competent individual could have ascertained from the material i have tried to ingest, enough to have figured it out by now, but apparently I am not as bright I would like to believe.

Thank you in advance for any help you may be able to render.
 Python2.7, 3.2 PyQt4, Pyside, PyQt-x11-gpl-4.9.1 on Linux Ubuntu 11.10.
I have been using 2.7, PyQt4 up to this point.

Comment: It would be better if you post your trial and where you got stuck. Otherwise there are tons of examples that ship with PyQt4. Check the examples folder in PyQt4 install directory.

Comment: Been there, done that. But to no avail. As far as posting my code goes, I've no idea how to even start. I've grabbed bit's and pieces of other examples I've googled and sort of patched a few into my app, but get numerous error msgs. It seems from the info I've found that QProcess is the way to go, but once again, the QT and PyQT4 sites might as well be written in Sanskrit, for all that i can get out of it.

Comment: If you are going to run a python code, `QThread` is the way. `QProcess` is for *external* programs. At least show a sample program that you want to integrate with GUI. Anything I come up with might be irrelevant to your case and might as well end up being another Sanskrit junk on the top of your pile :).

Comment: Thanks for your time, Avaris. I have already generated a Qt file in designer, that consists of a main window with 2 QPlainTextEdit windows, One for input another to display output from my main python app. The main app is a aiml Chatbot with additions. I have converted the QT ui file into a python script using pyuic4. So I already have 2 python files going. I am thinking it may be best to use a third as a frontend and have the other 2 feed into it. I figure it may be cleaner and help me keep everything sorted out. I will definitively check out your suggestion, as far as QThread goes.Thanks

Comment: I'll post a sample script as answer. Hopefully it'll provide an appropriate example to how integrate things.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple script for integrating existing python script with GUI.

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
import time

# some python function to integrate with GUI
def factorial(n):
    if n in (0,1):
        return 1
    else:
        return n*factorial(n-1)


# worker thread that will run our function
class Worker(QtCore.QThread):
    # custom signal that will be emitted when an output is ready
    # 'int' instead of 'object' will result in C++ int and might overflow.
    # object makes sure it is a python object
    resultReady = QtCore.pyqtSignal(object)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Worker, self).__init__(parent)

    def setUp(self, n):
        self.n = n

    def run(self):
        time.sleep(1)  # dummy sleep to emulate 'working' status
        self.result = factorial(self.n)
        self.resultReady.emit(self.result)


# Main GUI window
class Main(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Main, self).__init__(parent)

        # setup widgets
        self.input = QtGui.QLineEdit()
        self.output = QtGui.QLineEdit()
        self.button = QtGui.QPushButton('Calculate Factorial')
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.calculate)

        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.input)
        layout.addWidget(self.output)
        layout.addWidget(self.button)

        centralWidget = QtGui.QWidget()
        centralWidget.setLayout(layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)

        # setup worker thread and connect signal
        self.worker = Worker(self)
        self.worker.resultReady.connect(self.updateOutput)

    def calculate(self):
        try:
            n = int(self.input.text())
            # setup thread
            self.worker.setUp(n)
            # start thread
            self.worker.start()
        except ValueError:
            pass

    def updateOutput(self, result):
        # will be called when we have a result
        # and put that result in appropriate widget
        self.output.setText('%d' % result)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = Main()

    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: AVARIS, THANKS BIG TIME! I've just now checked back in to this site, and low and behold, found this most gracious gift of your time. I can't wait to bisect it. May your tribe increase! Assuming you're into big tribes.:) I'll start, in my usual slow and prodding way right after I've posted my thanks to you. Sorry if my lack of posting, had may your job of helping me any harder then it might have been. Thanks once more and I will let you know how I make out.